# 3-D Golden Angle

Tags: matrices, number-theory, matrix-equations

I'm trying to find a 3D analog for the [golden angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_angle), g. In particular, I'm interested in the following property of the golden angle:
Let $M_2$ be the rotation matrix that rotates by g. Then, for all n>1,
$$ n^2\left | I_2-M_2^n \right |>\gamma_2 $$
For some constant $\gamma_2>0$, where $I_2$ is the 2x2 identity matrix. For the golden angle, $\gamma_2=\frac{4\pi^2}{5}$. I think this uniquely defines g, if we add the condition that $|M_2|=1$, up to a sign (not sure how to prove that).
By analogy, I'm wondering how to solve for the analog in higher dimensions. Namely, I'm wondering if there is a 3x3 matrix $M_3$ and a constant $\gamma_3>0$ such that, $|M_3|=1$, and for all n>1
$$ n^3\left | I_3-M_3^n \right |>\gamma_3 $$
I'd greatly appreciate any and all help or any suggestions.

Comment: The syntax of this question confuses me - in the first case, you have "given a matrix defined by g, we can find a constant..." You have found the constant by some means. But a similar theorem would not specify the matrix or constant, if you need one to have the other... Do you mean to take $ \gamma_2=\gamma_3 $?

Comment: For almost all matrices, we cannot find a constant $ \gamma_2 > 0 $ that satisfies the condition. We can get arbitrarily close to the unitary matrix (or get it exactly) if we choose a large enough n. 
The constant is specific only to the dimension, I believe. Maybe this no longer holds in higher dimensions, but I suspect it does. There should be a set of matrices that all share the same gamma.

Comment: Notice that any rotation in 3d is just a 2d rotation about a certain axis. So the basis vector $e_1$ will form a cone as it is rotated about a certain axis. Since the axes are just forming more circles with possible rotations, which have radius at most $1$, they seem to be staying relatively close to their original positions. I'm not sure such a $\gamma_3$ exists.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right, based on trying out a few things. Working on developing a different analog for the 3-D golden angle.